# Azure Pipeline job using container fails validation

Tags: azure-devops, containers, azure-pipelines

I wanted to start using containers within by YAML build pipeline in Azure DevOps. The pipeline works just fine if I exclude the following code snippet.

```
container:
  image: my-image-name:1.0
  endpoint: my-endpoint-in-ado
```

When I tried following approach the pipeline validated, but then of course failed authentication since the repository is private

```
container: my-image-name:1.0
```

I'm not sure whether I am missing something trivial, but when I contacted colleague from another team he has it implemented in the same way but for him it works.
The error I'm getting via Azure DevOps UI is following (keep in mind that the error is gone if I remove the container section):

[image]

EDIT:
I've found out that the problem I am facing is because (for some reason) when adding *containers* section to *resources* the engine cannot read anymore the information from the *repositories* section. On picture below, when I remove lines 7, 29 and 30 everything works fine and the container is pulled in the pipeline. Problem is, that I need that variable from line 29 further in my scripts and as far as I know there is no other way to grab the details of *repositories* via other variables or any other way than I am already using.

[image]

Comment: Hi Tadeáš, Does my answer work? Please check it and kindly let me know the result. Thanks.

Comment: @EdwardHan-MSFT please see my edit in original post.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps to check the result.

- By reference to this doc: [Build and push to Azure Container Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/containers/acr-template?view=azure-devops), we succeed to push my own image to an Azure container registry.
- By reference to this doc: [Container reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#container-reference) and [Container resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#container-resource), we need to create a [Docker Registry service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-docreg) which type is Azure Container Registry. And we enable "*Grant access permission to all pipelines*" option so this service connection can be used in all pipelines without additional authentication. Please note that this service connection should be successfully validated before using it in yaml pipeline.
- After these actions, we can succeed to use this [container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#container-resource) in yaml pipeline, like below.

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

resources:
  containers:
  - container: linux
    image: edwardregistery.azurecr.io/pipelines-javascript-docker:latest
    endpoint: my_acr_connection # reference to a service connection for the private registry

jobs:
- job: a
  container: linux # reference
  steps:

  - script: echo "hello world!"
```

**Update**>>I can reproduce your issue `An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. Value cannot be null. Parameter name: values` when setting variable `variables: - name: active_branch  value: $[ replace(resources.repositories['test'].ref, 'refs/heads/', '') ]`if there are [container resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#container-resource) and [repository resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#repository-resource) in [yaml resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#resources). However, it works if you remove container resource and there is only the repository resource. We suggest that you submit it [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem) to contact the product group to investigate this issue further.

Comment: I found out that the problem I am having is, because I am using both containers and repositories in my resources in the main pipeline. Adding the containers section for some reason makes it impossible to get the reference and other values from the repositories. When I removed the lines referencing to the values from the repositories, it started working fine, but that brought one more complication, because I need to have those values at my disposal

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check it and kindly let me know the result.

Comment: I have created it there as well couple days ago. Here's a link to it https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Not-able-to-reference-repositories-when/1392302?space=21&entry=problem

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, and the DC thread is under investigation, so you could monitor it to get latest feedback from the product group.

Answer (score 0):

To those whom it may concern (I will answer my own question as I have worked on a fix).

I've spent almost 8 months working on this problem with Microsoft support, until they finally admitted that this was indeed a bug and said that they are working on a solution, which took about 8 months to develop and deploy to Azure DevOps.

Nevertheless, this issue shouldn't occur anymore, as I have tested this in autumn 2022 and confirmed with Microsoft that the issue is resolved. So in the end, now you can use both scopes, meaning you can use Containers AND variables from the Repositories scopes.